# Authorization empty endpoint Bot Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, bearer-token, skype-for-business

## Context :

I'm working on a bot project with azure.
I made a "**bot channel registration**" where I could setup an endpoint to receive the message from **Skype Business**. This endpoint is our server. I'm able to receive these messages on our server, However these messages **does not contain a bearer token**.
The code in our server is the **bot framework SDK** botbuilder in nodeJs. This SDK allows us to communicate with Azure and to treat the messages we receive (requests from users) and the messages we want to send (answers to users)

## Our issue :

To work properly, the SDK has to read the bearer token sent by azure. However, as explained previously, my message does not contain this bearer.

## Questions :

- Why there is no bearer in the headers sent by Azure ?
- How can I add this required bearer ?

### Additional information :

I don't have admin rights, I can see few things in my bot channel resource, but I can't see/modify config in the associated AAD.
(If actions of these questions require admin rights whom I haven't, explain me the process and I will transfer it to my admin azure)

Thanks in advance,

I've blocked for 4 weeks now, I really need help

Regards,

:)

Comment: How have you verified that req.headers.authorization has no Bearer token?

Comment: I'm able to receive the message on our server (without using the bot SDK 4). However, and because it's an azure pro, the  request must contain an bearer to be used in the SDK in a entreprise mode.
I know what you will say : "Use this request without using the SDK". I tried. But my server is not able to send a message to bot azure (and so to answer to a specific user with a specific conversation ID). I followed this tuto : [link](https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2016/08/19/build-skype-bot-with-microsoft-bot-framework-oauth-and-rest-api/) to call the desired bot API. but I'm not authorized

Comment: to link the request and the SDK 4, I have to do in NodeJS a "adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter(appID, psswdID)" and also a restify server. Then in the post path server, I have to run "adapter.processActivity" -->  This is a basic template for an echo bot

Comment: Can you share the code you are using? What is the BotHandle?

Answer (score 0):

The Skype for Business channel for the Bot Framework is being deprecated:

[image]

Comment: Yes I saw that. Deprecated but it remains active. And our end-users are too familiar with SkypeForBusiness to change with Teams. Maybe in the next year. But once we will connect it to SfB, it will be easier to connect it with Teams too